# Probability that at least 5 adjacent length-4 blocks of a certain kind occur in a string of 26 random digits

Tags: probability, combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, pi

Let a "$(4,2)$-block" be any string of four digits exactly two of which are equal.

**Question**: What is the probability that in a string of $26$ decimal digits, chosen independently and uniformly at random, there occur *at least $5$ adjacent non-overlapping* $(4,2)$-blocks?

An example of this occurring would be the outcome $141592(6535)(8979)(3238)(4626)(4338).$ The $1415$ block is not counted because it is not adjacent to the other five.

So far, I have only a poor upper bound using Boole's inequality.  If we let $A$ denote the event whose probability we seek, then $A$ is the union of the following seven events, where each 'xxxx' denotes some $(4,2)$-block and each 'y' denotes an *arbitrary* digit:

```
A1:  xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx yyyyyy
A2:  y xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx yyyyy
A3:  yy xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx yyyy
A4:  yyy xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx yyy
A5:  yyyy xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx yy
A6:  yyyyy xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx y
A7:  yyyyyy xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx
```

With hopefully obvious notation, we have, by Boole's inequality,

$P(xxxx)\\ 
\le P(ee..)+P(e.e.)+P(e..e)+P(.ee.)+P(.e.e)+P(..ee)\\
\le 6\times ({10\times 100\over 10^4})\\
\le{3\over 5}$

where 'e's denote the equal digits and '.'s denote arbitrary digits. Then, again by Boole's inequality,

$P(A)\\
\le P(A_1)+\dots+P(A_7)\\
\le 7\times({3\over 5})^5\\
\le 0.544$

Comment: A random string of four digits is a $(4,2)$-block with probability $6\times\left(\frac{10\times9\times8}{10^4}\right)=0.432$ This gives $P(A_i)\approx 0.015$ Your upper bound is then $P(A)\le 0.105$ Simulation gives a result of $\approx 0.0796$

Comment: @DanielMathias Thanks! I don't know how I overlooked that exact probability of a $(4,2)$-block; also, consistent with your simulations, mine give (using $10^9$ samples) $P(A)≈0.07961 \pm 0.00003\ $. I wonder whether there is a not-too-messy way of finding the exact value of $P(A).$